# why can't I pass the name of the table to get the table from DataSet.tables?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a custom table. Here is the information about the custom table. Here are the names of the table

Table Name : customtable_TwitterCacheTable

Why can't I access the table by using the Table Name,

so in my code, if I do this, I will get a NullReference Exception

```
   foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["customtable_TwitterCacheTable"].Rows)
                    {
                    CustomTableItem deleteItem = new CustomTableItem(row, customTableClassName);

                    deleteItem.Delete();

                }
```

But the following seems work OK

```
   foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
```

Why can't I pass the name of the table in to get a table? Do I have to use this index based approach?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Confirm that you have given that table a name in the dataset and that it matches.

Comment: yes, i have checked with the database. the name provided is correct

Comment: I did the query in SQL select * from customtable_TwitterCacheTable and it returns the rows fine. But as soon as I do this ds.Tables["customtable_TwitterCacheTable"].Rows I get Null Exception

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually name the table in the dataset. Unless its excplicitly named, its only known as ds.tables[0]. Depending on how you get the data you could:

```
//if you used a SqlDataAdapter
da.Fill(ds, "customtable_TwitterCacheTable");
```

Or you could do this:

```
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "customtable_TwitterCacheTable";
```